# Fixed width page layout, but adjustable with content

Tags: css, html

I want to upgrade my website's template.
I want the content to be in a fixed width centered div. This is not a problem and there are many examples on the web.
Since I have already content with text & tables, I want to make sure that the div will not cut  the content of some pages.
I don't want to use Javascript to adjust the width.
Is there a way to do this with a div or should I use table instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not getting your question right, centered as in vertically too? If you want it vertically centered than you need to use `position: absolute;` and if you want it horizontally centered you just need to use `margin: auto;`, as simple as that...

```
/* Totally center fixed width content */

.center {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin-top: /* Half of the total height of the container div */
   margin-left: /* Half of the total width of the container div */
}
```

If you need the content horizontally centered, you need to use

```
.horizontal {
   margin: auto;
}
```

Content won't be cropped unless and until you use a `fixed width div` and `overflow: hidden;` at the same time

Comment: Only centered width, but the main issue is to adjust the width when the content is too big (e.g: big table or big image)

Comment: Use a fixed width div and `margin: auto;` it will center the things up, for the content larger than the containers, use `overflow: auto;`